# Black screen during full screen playback on 2015 MacBook Pro retina

Tags: video, displayport

Any streaming video played back full screen results in periodic black screens, as if it's buffering, but it only happens with the mini DP connection, not HDMI, and doesn't happen with locally stored video or windowed playback. It happens in Chrome/Edge and VLC, not in Safari. Also doesn't happen in Chrome/Edge if I disable hardware acceleration, at the expense of a much reduced framerate.

Comment: I am trying to follow, but it got confusing how disabling HW accel. in your browser would have any effect on stand alone players.  As for your mDP connection, are you going mDP from the Mac to DP to the display?

Comment: No, HW accel only affects the browser, haven't tried it in VLC. Using mini DP on both ends.

Comment: To rule out the display, is it possible to connect to a different display (using DP of course) to see if it happens there?  Also, try taking a screen shot (it will have to be non-DRM video), one with HDMI connected and another with DP.  This way we can “see” what’s in the GPU.

Comment: What OS are you running? I'd try to get more data about which apps works and which don't.

Comment: macOS 12.6.6. I suspect that since it occurs in Chromium and VLC, but not in Safari, its perhaps a bug in an underlying library like ffmpeg, but the mDP/HDMI behavior is a mystery.